# append заменяет значения в списке вместо добавления, помогите решить проблему

Tags: python, append

[image: Консоль][image: Фрагмент кода где возникает проблема]
!!!
[cvs file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dcSEQaH5xw5voZQ3qwb91SmBW7ghuKzJ/view?usp=sharing)

```
import csv 
    
    try:
        with open("API_SP.DYN.LE00.IN_DS2_en_csv_v2_1622191.csv", encoding='utf-8') as r_file:
            file_reader = csv.reader(r_file, delimiter=",")
            count = 0
            arr = [[]]
            arr2 = [[]]
            for row in file_reader:
                if count > 3:
                    str = ", ".join(row)
                    List = str.split(', ')
                    arr.append(List)
                count += 1
            print(f'Всего в файле {count} строк.')
    except Exception:
        print("Ошибка при чтении файла")
    
    arr.pop(0)
    arr2.clear()
    List = []
    List.clear()
    for i in arr:
        n = 0
        List.clear()
        for j in i:
            if n > 4:
                if j == '':
                    break
                List.append(j)
            n += 1
            #print("arr2 = ", arr2, "\n\n" , "list = ", List)
            
        arr2.append(List)
    
    
    List3 = arr2[224]
    List4 = arr2[227]
    
    print(List3)
    print("\n\n\n")
    print(List4)
```

Comment: Как прикрепить файл csv?

Comment: Спасибо прикрепил

Answer (score 2):

Проблема была в том что List как бы не был list

```
List = list(List)     
arr2.append(List)
```

Answer (score 0):

Уж не знаю как у вас это без ошибок выполнялось и дошло до вашего вывода, что append не добавляет, а заменяет. Как бы он не может заменять, он действительно добавляет.

```
import csv 
# вообще бы надо было следующие строки arr = [] и так же arr2 = [] 
arr = [[]] # уж не знаю зачем именно так инициализировать списки
arr2 = [[]] # но важно это было сделать здесь, а не внутри открытия файла

try:
    with open("API_SP.DYN.LE00.IN_DS2_en_csv_v2_1622191.csv", encoding='utf-8') as r_file:
        file_reader = csv.reader(r_file, delimiter=",")
        count = 0
        for row in file_reader:
            if count > 3:
# !!! не используйте зарезервированные слова для переменных - str системный объект строки, неужели бкув мало что бы другое имя переменной дать? изменил на st
                st = ", ".join(row) 
                List = st.split(', ')
                arr.append(List)
            count += 1
        print(f'Всего в файле {count} строк.')
except Exception:
    print("Ошибка при чтении файла")

arr.pop(0) # не менее странные очистки списков... в них еще ничего нет, что б чистить их...
arr2.clear() # и здесь тоже.
List = []
List.clear()
for i in arr:
    n = 0
    List.clear()
    for j in i:
        if n > 4:
            if j == '':
                break
            List.append(j)
        n += 1

    arr2.append(List)

List3 = arr2[224]
List4 = arr2[227]

print(List3)
print("\n\n\n")
print(List4)
```

Вот такой код работает и что-то выводит.

Comment: Вообще код не хороший. Надо его переписать, излишки удалить. Сделать более лаконичным.